# Change query in IIS Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a problem when my site gets called like this example.com/products&clid=test123 then my page breaks cause asp.net considers this dangerous

Been trying to do Rewrite in IIS to change it to ?clid=test123 but im stuck at it. Any ideas to how this can be done ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will work for you

```
<rule name="Redirect clid" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)&amp;clid=(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}?clid={R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

It will redirect all requests, which have `....&clid=....` into `....?clid=....`